# Подскажите хостинги с возможностью удалённого доступа к PostgeSQL

Tags: postgresql, хостинг

интересует собственно сабж. Раньше такая возможность была у Sweb, которым я многие годы пользовался, сегодня обнаружил, что удалённый доступ можно настроить только к MySQL. Поковырялся в предложениях популярных отечественных хостеров - не нашёл. У Yandex.Cloud цена несколько тысяч рублей в месяц, что для моего проекта несоразмерно много.

Comment: Возьмите любой vps.

Comment: Digital Ocean предоставляет такое удовольствие, там даже кластер можно навернуть в пару кликов.